# Use existing models in swagger that are in other project fo swagger code-gen

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

This is the context:
I'm using swagger to build the structure of my API with swagger code-generator
But my first problem is that actually that API will have a dependency of Common-Entities.

```
My-Java-Swagger-Project
   -Controller
   -Entities(model)
   -Everything else
My-commons-project
   -Common Entities
```

So if Swagger generator will build "My-java-swagger-project" and I'm going to use entities of My-commons-project on it, how can I indicate swagger to generate and use existing classes of my commons project, or do not build the entities that I already have in commons project

```
definitions:
  Response:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      status:
        type: "string"
        description: "Returns if it was successful or not. "
      errors:
        type: "array"
        items: 
          $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorTO"
  Request:
    type: "object"
    required:
      - subject
      - messageText
    properties:
      subject:
        type: "string"
      messageText:
        type: "string"
  ErrorTO: #This one must not be defined in swagger because it's on my #commons project
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: "string"
      description:
        type: "string"
```

When I run **Swagger codegen outputs ErrorTO entity, but I already have in other project**, so how can I define swagger to do not create that entity and use the one of my commons (or only to do not create it)

Answer (score 0):

You can define `importMappings` and `typeMappings` to the code gen to tell it to use imported classes.  Not sure which generator you are using, but I sue ith with the Java/spring-boot server stub generator.  i sue the maven plugin, soemthing like

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.codegen.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>foo</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <importMappings>
            <importMapping>Foo=com.example.common.Foo</importMapping>
          </importMappings>
          <typeMappings>
            <typeMapping>Foo=com.example.common.Foo</typeMapping>
          <typeMappings>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
 </plugin>
```